# Remove out all text that are under "(" and ")"

Tags: php

I have a table

```
|----------|-----------------------------------------|------------------|
|    id    |        name                             |    desc          |
|----------------------------------------- ----------|------------------|
|    123   |   Empire : Kill (Kill everybody now)    |    desc 1        |
|----------------------------------------------------|------------------|
|    243   |   Witch : Show (Bloodthirst part 2)     |    desc 2        |
|----------------------------------------------------|------------------|
```

I am writing the following code to extract data from table

```
$columns_total  = mysql_num_fields($result); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //retrieving each row 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) 
        {
            /*appending each column data into the row of the data 
                encapsulated within double quotes and separated by a comma */
            $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
        }
    }
```

But, I have to check whether `$row[$i]` is value of `name` column or `desc` column.
If it's `name` column then the text under brackets will be removed, else not.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: There are others, but this is probably the easiest one. Why are they stored like that in the first place? It might be better to seperate these blocks into multiple columns.

Comment: Like previuos user already say your stored data is incorrect. If you anyway need to split the string, you can try to find then ":" character and then show just the first part of the string

Comment: Even if the output matches, conceptually your solution is wrong. You're not removing stuff between "(" and ")", you're just removing everything that's beyond "(". The solution Anthony D'Andrea suggested is the correct one to your question

Comment: @Bartserk check what my question is actually?? i want to know whether $row[$i] is value of name column or value of desc column...

Comment: @Saswat I'm writing an answer. You just edited the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the method `mysql_num_fields` you're getting the rows in a numbered array. This means the index you specify when you access to the $row array will determine which column you are accessing. To achieve this you have two solutions:

- You can generate a static correspondence column_name -> index according to the query you're using. If the $result variable contains something like `select * from table` the index will be number 1.
- You can get the list of fields using the method `mysql_list_fields` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php

So once you have which index is your man, you just have to do a simple conditional like `if ($row == 1) {trim();}` and you're done!

Comment: i want something like if($key == 'name') cause the data will be coming either from table 1 or table 2 having same column name but different index... i cant even use mysql_fetch_assoc... cause i need to use for loop with counter

Comment: Then you definitely need the method mysql_list_fields. Store that into a $variable and access it like $variable[1] == 'name'.

Comment: but what if when from table 1 $variable[1] can become name, while from table 2 $variable[4] becomes name??

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = preg_replace('/\(.*\)/','',$data);
```

And get rid of space

```
$data = trim($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode it by :

```
$format_array = explode(":",$data);
$format_data = $format_array[0];
echo $format_data.':';
```

Answer (score -1):

You could explode the code after the "(" character and then remove the space at the end with the "trim" function :

```
$input = "Empire : (Kill everybody now)";

$input2 = explode("(",$input);

$input3 = trim($input2[0]);
```

Now `$input3` variable is holding the result you are looking for.