# How to check whether a column-name is "name" or not?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table:-

```
|----------|-----------------------------------------|------------------|
|    id    |        name                             |    desc          |
|----------------------------------------- ----------|------------------|
|    123   |   Empire : Kill (Kill everybody now)    |    desc 1        |
|----------------------------------------------------|------------------|
|    243   |   Witch : Show (Bloodthirst part 2)     |    desc 2        |
|----------------------------------------------------|------------------|
```

I am writing the following code to extract data from table:-

```
$columns_total  = mysql_num_fields($result); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //retrieving each row 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) 
        {
            /*appending each column data into the row of the data 
                encapsulated within double quotes and separated by a comma */
            $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
        }
    }
```

I have to check whether `$row[$i]` is value of `name` column or `desc` column??

If it is `name` column, then the text under brackets will be removed, else not

How can I achieve that?

Comment: so what?? i can use `desc`.... can't i? i mean encapsulating desc within back-tilt

Comment: you can correctly quoted. Just have to always remember, Its usually avoided for that reason

Comment: Whilst it was primarily asking about string searching, your previous question [Remove out all text that are under "(" and ")"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317352/remove-out-all-text-that-are-under-and) seems to have gotten an answer to this already?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [**associative**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) array.. also a foreach loop, like so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) //retrieving each row's ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY 
    {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value)  // $key will hold the name of the field
        {
            // now you can go like this:
            if($key != 'name')
                $output .= '"'.$value.'",';
            else
                // whatever you want 

        }
    }
```

Just as a side note, `mysql_` functions are deprecated. You should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)). That way, your results come back:

```
array (
    'id'=>123,
    'name'=>"Whatever the name is",
    'desc'=>"desc 1"
);
foreach ($row as $name=>$value)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `foreach`

```
foreach($row as $key => $value)
{
     if($key == 'name')
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

`$key` will be the index key of the array and `$value` is the value of that so

`'key' => 'value'`